# se guarda vacio los campos string en la base de datos sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Buenas tardes tengo un problema al guardar datos de tipo string en la base de datos y es que no me los guarda que puedo hacer gracias, registra vacio.

Comment: Hola @Juan. Por favor brinda más detalles. Por ejemplo, ¿qué código estás utilizando para guardar en la base de datos, cómo ejecutas dicho código, en qué ambiente y sistema operativo trabajas, estás seguro que trabajas con la base de datos correcta, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, la verdad no das muchos datos por lo que no sabemos si estas utilizando el SQLite desde la consola, o intentas hacerlo desde algun otro leguaje de programación, pero supongo que lo que necesitas es confirmar la transacción con el comando COMMIT;

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 );

commit;
```